# Как запомнить найденный уязвимый параметр в sqlmap

Tags: sql, kali-linux

sqlmap перепробовал некоторое количество тестов затем вывел сообщение о том что нашел уязвимый параметр

```
[20:13:39] [INFO] POST parameter 'username' appears to be 'PostgreSQL stacked queries (heavy query)' injectable
```

После этого я прервал сканирование.
Есть ли какой нибудь удобный способ запомнить где sqlmap нашел уязвимость и сразу ее использовать? или нужно начинать сканирование каждый раз вновь ?

Comment: ) Возможно в этой статье вы найдете ответы на свои вопросы, рекомендую к прочтению)
https://codeby.net/threads/ispolzovanie-sqlmap-na-kali-linux-vzlom-veb-sajtov-i-baz-dannyx-cherez-sql-inekcii.67238/

Comment: Благодарю, ознакомлюсь